# Error connecting to SQL Server from Workiva Chains

Tags: sql-server

We use Workiva Wdesk/Wdata for various reporting projects. We are trying to set up the new feature called Wdata Chains to connect to SQL Server for data import. Here is the error I'm getting.

> The TCP/IP connection to the host DEVSQLDB1, port 1433 has failed.
> Error: "DEVSQLDB1. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an
> instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP
> connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port
> are not blocked by a firewall.

hereis a snapshot of the error message.
[image]

Comment: Can you connect to SQL server with ssms? From another client (even Excel on read only) on the same machine and on a distant machine to know whether the problem is SQL server or wdata. If you can connect with ssms then you can check more settings.

Comment: I guess the most obvious questions are: Is there an instance of Microsoft SQL Server installed on DEVSQLDB1? Is it running? In SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager's Server Protocols, is the TCP/IP protocol enabled? Is it configured to accept connections on tcp/1433? Does Windows Firewall allow incoming connections on tcp/1433?